# What Leiningen path can't Cursive locate? (IntelliJ Clojure IDE)

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, clojure, leiningen, cursive

I'm trying out Cursive, a Clojure IDE on top of IntelliJ. The Leiningen console works, but prints a "path not found" error.

[image]

I can't seem to figure out what it can't locate. Leiningen appears to be working, though. Any idea how I can figure out what it can't locate, and fix it?

I'm on Windows 8.1 64-bit, using IntelliJ 14.0.2, and Cursive 0.1.43.

Comment: Think it could be related to this: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/1617

Comment: When using Leiningen via command prompt I never encounter any issues. It only occurs when used within IntelliJ.

Comment: is this still broken your you?

Comment: It is, unfortunately. It's not in my way, but it's just an annoyance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce this issue with IntelliJ 14.0.2 (Community Ed.) + Cursive 0.1.43. My IntelliJ's Leiningen output:

> ```
> C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\lein.bat version
> Leiningen 2.5.0 on Java 1.8.0_25 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
> ```

One thing you could try is to use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to find out what file it's trying to access.

Configure it to only "Show File System Activity", exclude any Result=SUCCESS records, and retry your action. You'll still get lots of events but hopefully if you apply more filtering, you'll be able to pinpoint what file it's trying to access.

Another thing is: are you running any anti virus/malware software? How about if you try disabling it?

Comment: I'm not running any anti-virus or anything. I just tried the process monitor suggestion and there were definitely a lot of things to filter through. I don't know if this is the appropriate filter, but I filtered it down to things with the `NO SUCH FILE` result. Here's a screenshot on the files not found after I run `lein.bat version` via Cursive / IntelliJ: http://i.imgur.com/xclc0z8.png

Comment: Your output for `NO SUCH FILE` looks the same as in my PC. How about for `PATH NOT FOUND` and `NAME NOT FOUND`? You can find mine here: http://i.imgur.com/KGPp3pS.png. You can go to Tools|Count Occurences to get summary